# MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER,while trying to do PhoneAuth in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to do a Phone Authentication Method using Firebase Auth, I've made sure that all the steps are followed, adding my package name,adding SHA Key using

> keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore"
>   -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

and then adding all the dependencies and also including the json file into my project

Now I'm sending my Phone number in a **+CountryCodeXXXXX** format and for some reason, it gives me a **MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER** in `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks()` method,any inputs would be helpfull

Here's my code

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    mCallbacks= new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Verification Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Verification Failed "+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
}




@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnSend:
            String temp = editText.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),temp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                    temp,        // Phone number to verify
                    60,                 // Timeout duration
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                    this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                    mCallbacks);
    break;




    }
}
```

Comment: It did not occur on a different device.

Answer (score 11):

I've determined through trial and error (annoyingly undocumented) that this happens when you have disabled the captcha request (or silent APN request) firebase uses to verify app environment, and you are trying to sign in on a non-white-listed number.

`fbAuth.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = YES;`

^Change this back to NO and it will all work again.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem, it was because i tried and tested to many times using same device with my wifi network as well as mobile network. So somehow they blocked the request for this client id. As soon as i tried it in different device with different network everything was fine. While developing just [whitelisting a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wesE.png) and provide verification code for it

Answer (score 2):

For Swift

- `true`: testing phone number
- `false`: real phone number

```
Auth.auth().settings?.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = false
```

Testing phone numbers can be setting here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you **DON'T** use the number that you entered in for testing and setting `Auth.auth().settings?.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = true`.

Steps.

1- You enter a whitelisted a number *12125551212* for testing in the console:

[image]

2- Then to bypass the captcha, you try to login and use:

```
Auth.auth().settings?.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = true // <-- specifically set this to true for testing to skip the captcha


// the phoneNumberTextField.text is 18008881234
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { ... }
```

3- But instead of using the whitelisted number that you provided in step-1, you used a different number:

18008881234 (this ISN'T the number you provided in step 1)

In short, to **avoid this problem**, just **use whatever number you provided in step-1** when using **Auth.auth().settings?.isAppVerificationDisabledForTesting = true** for login testing