# An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER ] while verifying phone number

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting `An internal error has occurred. [ MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER ]` error while verifying the phone number using `Firebase`. Everything was working fine but all of a sudden, I am getting the aforementioned error.

For reference, I'm getting a callback in the following function:

```
@Override
public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
    MyProgressDialog.dismissProgress();
    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid credential:" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS exceeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error:" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45917917/missing-client-identifier-while-trying-to-do-phoneauth-in-android)?

Comment: I am not using the same number again @Piyush

Comment: Not same number. It's all about same device.

Comment: @Piyush I also tried on the different device but still getting the same response

Comment: Try once with different device network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been using the same phone number to test this verification a significant number of times? Firebase blocks client ids that make too many requests.

Try with another phone number and if it works perfectly fine, then the client id against this number is certainly blocked for now.

Comment: thanks for your response,  i am mostly using a different number for testing.

Comment: Have you tried devices connected to different network, as in different wifi?

Comment: no, I have not tried this, but if I am using the same device same number and same internet connection then how will I manage because I need OTP verification every time user login.

Comment: You can whitelist this number as it's been referred in the aforementioned answer.

Comment: i already checked this too, but my point is  if i am using same phone same number and the same network then how will i manage? this is only my concern. :(

Comment: It depends on the request how much you do?

Comment: thanks for your time and efforts both of you Piyush and ahmedaljubair

Comment: @Piyush nope, its just i can't do anything in this bcz its what firebase developers doing so handling things accordingly